# Add/remove to parameters to request URL

Tags: java, url-routing, httprequest, atg, atg-dynamo

I have a method

```
public void service(DynamoHttpServletRequest request,DynamoHttpServletResponse response){}
```

which gets called on request. To this request url am trying to make changes to its parameters. I can use

```
request.setParameter()
```

But I have a key with two different values. If I use `request.setParameter()`  the second value will replace the first one as shown below.

```
URL-  ***"host/abc.jsp?extra=124&extra=12"***
suppose (extra,"124");
(extra,"12");
```

I changed the values **"124" to "abc" and "12" to "cd"** .. Here am not able to add the second value to the url .Upon completion of the method am getting the urls as  ***"host/abc.jsp?extra=cd"*** the first value is lost.
Please suggest some solution.

Comment: In general servlet request parameters will be stored as map of key/value and you can't store two keys with same name. I don't think it is possible to have same name keys in url.

Comment: Nope it works.. If you give multiple values for same key, It takes the values as string[] type.. check this..Its related to atg.. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/apidoc/atg/servlet/MutableHttpServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()

Comment: If you use this request.getParameterMap() ..you get <String,String[]>..type <key,value> pairs..

Comment: it seems atg specific feature. I need to check how it works in HttpServlet. I don't know much about atg.

Comment: It is same for both..reference-->http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: :Got it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting all the 'extra' values in an array and set it as the parameter:

```
String[] extraArr = {"123","456"};
request.setParameter("extra",extraArr);
```